# Spring Security still authenticated after restart (but no session)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using spring boot to launch a spring application.  What I am finding is that if my user is logged in and I need to restart the spring boot application the user appears to stay logged in, at least based on this code returning true:

```
<script sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:inline="javascript">
```

However, the session for the user is empty and the code I normally use to build up some local session data, the **onAuthenticationSuccess** method of my AuthSuccessHandler isn't called.

I can probably find some creative ways to fix this but I'd like to understand what is happening and what is a proper solution.

Answer (score 2):

Figured this out - in my application.yml I just needed:

```
server.servlet.session:
  persistent: false
```